# In Excel, how would you generate a random number x times

Tags: excel, random

In Excel, I can generate a random number with the formula:

RANDBETWEEN(1,A1)

Where the cell A1 holds the max number I want to generate. A use case would be a random dice roll generator. Enter 6 in A1 to roll a 6-sided dice.

How to I modify my formula to incorporate summing multiple random numbers. The use case would be roll 2 6-sided dice, where 2 comes from cell A2?

In other words, I want to specify x number of n-sided dice. If I specify 3d12, I want to sum the result of 3 random numbers from 1 to 12.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example? If one dice roll is 3, and the other is 5, do you want to show 8?

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN(1,A1) + RANDBETWEEN(1,A1)`?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it more clear what you're asking, because as written it is not. It wastes the time of people who write answers based on what you've written only to be told that you meant something else entirely. Be specific about what you're asking.

Comment: Any cell solution would have to either roll the same random number x times, or have an upper bound to the number of random numbers. The latter could be achieved with many cells calculating random numbers and an IF cell determining how many of these random numbers to add. The only way to get unbounded random numbers is to use vba.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for the energy and discussion you've put in to this. I'm more than sorry I didn't check this sooner. I'm playing D&D and want a simply way to roll 4d20. Where I would get the sum of 4 random rolls of a 20 sided dice. I know how to get a random number between 1 and 20, but I don't know how to get the sum of 4 different random numbers.

Comment: @pnuts cleaned up mine as well. ty

Comment: @KenWhite if you downvoted, you should consider reverting your vote following the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill a few cells from, say, `B1` to `B10` with `=RANDBETWEEN(1, A1)` so you generate a bunch of rolls. Then on `C1` enter: `=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,$A$2,1))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change input cells to suit. Where:

- A1 = the number of rolls
- B1 = the number of sides
- A2 will output the sum of the individually (psudo)random rolls.

  ```
  Sub rollDice()

  Dim rolls As Integer
  Dim sides As Integer
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer

  rolls = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
  sides = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
  x = 0
  y = 0


  While x < rolls
      y = y + Application.RandBetween(1, sides)
      x = x + 1
  Wend

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = y

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I have to give it to you, this would solve it, and in a more elegant way. I was simply looking for a solution using Excel formulas. I know VBA is a part of office, but if I'm diving into code, I'd use Javascript or something else.

Comment: Good to hear that sir. Comment again if you have any trouble with it. I had to teach myself vba so I'm happy to help ease the pain for others.